# How to count lines of a file within date range in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, centos

I'm using centos on a server and I want to count a number of lines of a file within a specific date range? I'm trying to debug my program.

```
2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:07+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:07+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:07+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:00
```

The data will be something like that now if I want to count how many lines are there in that file given date range from `2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00 - 2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:00` inclusive. Is that possible?

The result should be 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compare them normally: *you can compare your timestamps using alphanumeric comparisons and get the correct answer - that is the beauty of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169796/1983854)).

```
awk -v ini="2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00" -v end="2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:00" \
 '$0>=ini && $0<=end {sum++} END{print sum}'
```

With your file:

```
$ awk -v ini="2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00" -v end="2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:00" '$0>=ini && $0<=end {sum++} END{print sum}' file
10
```

With a more representative input:

```
$ cat t
2015-06-30T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-29T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:05+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:07+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:07+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:09+00:00
2016-06-30T14:10:08+00:00
2016-07-30T14:09:08+00:00
$ awk -v ini="2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00" -v end="2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:00" '$0>=ini && $0<=end' t
2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:07+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:07+00:00
2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:00
```

Comment: Wow ! I initially thought it was a hard nut to crack.

Comment: @sjsam there are no hard nuts for awk : )

Comment: OMG didn't think it would be so obvious. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK awk cannot compare dates. Please show me some documentation that says it can. I made the mistake in the past of thinking something like this had worked.This as far as i can tell is just doing a string comparison which conveniently works out.

Comment: The alphanumeric comparison works only for US locales meaning YYMMDD. It will not work for DDMMYY locales. Just saying that.

Comment: @123 in fact you are right. Quoting [Jonathan Leffler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4169796/1983854): _The key observation is that you can compare your timestamps using alphanumeric comparisons and get the correct answer - that is the beauty of ISO 8601 notation._

Comment: @hek2mgl indeed! See my last comment (well, the one before this one :D) regarding ISO 8601.

Comment: @fedorqui what about change the time format into Arabian text :-D it can be hard for awk...

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep` with `-c` flag to get the count of instances, thanks to the suggestions in the comments.

```
grep -c 2016-06-30T14:09:0[6-8]+00:00 file
```

The pattern `[6-8]`, a regex to match all the logs between `2016-06-30T14:09:06+00:0` and `2016-06-30T14:09:08+00:0` in the file.

Using `grep` to get the content and `awk` to print the number of lines

```
grep 2016-06-30T14:09:0[6-8]+00:00 file | awk 'END{print NR}'
10
```

also `bash` word count `wc` util can be used, which was faster than `awk` as suggested by [`karakfa`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa) in comments.

```
grep 2016-06-30T14:09:0[6-8]+00:00 file | wc -l
10
```

Comment: `... | wc -l` is shorter.

Comment: Why not `grep -c` ?

Comment: note this syntax could be done in `awk` alone --> `awk '/2016-06-30T14:09:0[6-8]+00:00/ {sum++} END{print sum}' file`

Comment: @fedorqui I think this might be one of the few cases where grep is the better/simpler option.

Comment: @123 indeed, the `grep -c` is clear and easy for this case.