# Matching date timestamp using Awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have time stamp entry in a log file in 2nd column in format HH:MM:SS:mmm

eg snippet

```
15-01-2017 21:15:10:266
15-01-2017 21:15:10:389
15-01-2017 21:15:15:266
15-01-2017 21:15:12:124
15-01-2017 21:15:12:266
15-01-2017 21:15:15:266
15-01-2017 21:15:20:266
```

I am trying

```
awk '$2 == "21:15:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}"'
```

to match all the entries at 21:15 but this doesn't seem to be working. Why isn't it working? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$2 == regexp`. But to check regexps in `awk` you need to use `~`, otherwise `==` is checking the string literally:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^21:15:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}/' file
```

This returns:

```
15-01-2017 21:15:10:266
15-01-2017 21:15:10:389
15-01-2017 21:15:15:266
15-01-2017 21:15:12:124
15-01-2017 21:15:12:266
15-01-2017 21:15:15:266
15-01-2017 21:15:20:266
```

From the [GNU awk user's guide on 3.1 How to Use Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Usage.html):

> Regular expressions can also be used in matching expressions. These expressions allow you to specify the string to match against; it need not be the entire current input record. The two operators ‘~’ and ‘!~’ perform regular expression comparisons. Expressions using these operators can be used as patterns, or in if, while, for, and do statements. (See Statements.) For example, the following is true if the expression exp (taken as a string) matches regexp:
>
> ```
> exp ~ /regexp/
> ```

Also from [6.3.2.2 Comparison Operators](http://6.3.2.2%20Comparison%20Operators):

> String comparisons and regular expression comparisons are very different. For example:
>
> ```
> x == "foo"
> ```
>
> has the value one, or is true if the variable x is precisely ‘foo’. By contrast:
>
> ```
> x ~ /foo/
> ```
>
> has the value one if x contains ‘foo’, such as "Oh, what a fool am I!".

Comment: Ok so you mean  $n ==  (where n is a column ) can only be used to match the exact string / value ?

Comment: @user3369871 exactly. See my edit with more references.

Comment: I get that , that being said  there shouldn't  be anything like  exp == / regex/  it has to be always syntactical to  exp ~ /regex/ ?

Comment: @user3369871 yes. I think it makes sense, so when you use `==` awk does not have to load the regex interpreter and sticks to the literals, thus being more agile.

Comment: :ok so  would taht  also mean that dynamic regex cannot be used in awk column search ?

Comment: @user3369871 not sure of what you mean here. Can you provide a specific case?

Comment: like in gensub() function you can use dynamic regex gensub ("regex","replacement pattern","g") . the regex expands with in double quotes  it doesn't have to be an exact string

Comment: @user3369871 no, in there you can use either `/ /` or `" "`: `awk 'BEGIN {a="he23llo"; print gensub(/[a-z]/,"","g",a)}'` and `awk 'BEGIN {a="hello"; print gensub("l","","g",a)}'`. So the `"regex"` notation here is a bit misleading.

Comment: thanks, I also used this  awk  '$2 >= "21:15:10" &&  $2 <= "21:15:20"'  to extract the lines between time range  this seems to be working   but not sure if  awk is actually able to understand it as time  values or  its  the simple string comparisons  that  brings out the correct result somehow between that range . Can you advise please? I am just trying to understand if awk can interpret time stamps as time values  or just as string?

Comment: There is no such type of timestamp in Awk, it just interprets these as strings and performs a string comparison. From [using awk to check between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4169796/1983854) _you can compare your timestamps using alphanumeric comparisons and get the correct answer - that is the beauty of ISO 8601 notation_.