# Filter Git Tags based on date

Tags: bash, git

I'm currently building a versioning pipeline that would automatically promote tags based on date. I am able to return all my tags with this command: `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)  | %(creatordate)" "refs/tags/*"`

Which outputs something like this:

```
v1.0.0  | Mon Jan 24 14:36:19 2022 -0600
v1.1.0  | Mon Jan 24 14:37:06 2022 -0600
v1.1.1  | Mon Jan 24 14:40:39 2022 -0600
v1.1.2  | Tue Jan 25 17:47:32 2022 +0000
v1.1.3  | Tue Jan 25 21:20:03 2022 +0000
v1.1.4  | Tue Jan 25 21:22:40 2022 +0000
v1.2.0  | Tue Jan 25 21:24:08 2022 +0000
v1.3.0  | Tue Jan 25 21:52:28 2022 +0000
```

I'm looking to take this output and filter it based on current date. So for example if I want all tags created after Jan 24, I'd need to filter this output to only return the tags created from the 25th and beyond.

I'm thinking `awk` could help with this but I'm uncertain.. Any tips would be great!

Comment: You don't need `awk` when you can use conditions in your `for-each-ref` with [`%(if)…​%(then)…​%(end)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-if).

Comment: As an afterthought, no, this conditional pattern doesn't suit your need, because it lacks "greater than" / "lesser than" operators. Only "equals" or "notequals"... sorry, you'll have to find another way.

Comment: On comparing dates in awk, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4163257/1256452).